# How to ask Mathematica to show the negative parts of $\sin x$ as some lines on the $x$ axis?

Tags: plotting

I want to ask Mathematica to show the domain of negative parts of the function $\sin x$ as red lines on the $x$ axis, like this picture

[image]

Is it possible to do it automatically? If not, I will be grateful if please tell me how I can do it manually.

`Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 20}]`

Comment: @user64494 - your approach can be used with `Plot[{Max[Sin[x], 0], Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 20},
 PlotStyle -> {Red, ColorData[97][1]}]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1.** Use `Plot` with two functions (`{Sin[x], If[Sin[x] <= 0, 0]}`) in the first argument:

```
Plot[{Sin[x], If[Sin[x] <= 0, 0]}, {x, 0, 20}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Directive[Red, Opacity[1], Thick]},
 Method -> {"AxesInFront" -> False}]
```

[image]

**2.** Use `NumberLinePlot` + `Plot`

```
Show[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 20}], 
 NumberLinePlot[Sin[x] < 0, {x, 0, 20}, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red], Spacings -> 0,
   Method -> {"AxesInFront" -> False}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Also `Mesh`, `MeshShading` and `MeshFunctions`

```
a = Plot[0, {x, 0, 20}, Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshFunctions -> (Sin[#] &), 
   MeshShading -> {Directive[Thickness[.01], Red], None}, 
   MeshStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Large], Green]];
b = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 20}];
Show[b, a]
```

[image]